# React Testing Library - Click all buttons returned by function

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
test("remove list when no entries are present", () => {
    render(<ListContainer />);
    seedEntries();
    expect(screen.getByRole("list")).toBeInTheDocument;
    screen.getAllByRole("button", { name: /\-/i }).forEach((entry) => {
        userEvent.click(entry)
    });
    expect(screen.queryByRole("list")).toBeNull();
});
```

Clicking the button calls the following function:

```
const handleDeleteEntry = (id) => {
        if (entries.length === 10) {
            setLimitError(false);
        }
        let filteredEntries = entries.filter((entry) => entry.id !== id);
        setEntries(filteredEntries);
    };
```

and my render method looks like this:

```
{entries.length > 0 ? (
    <ul>
        {entries.map((entry, index) => {
            return (
                <li
                    key={index}
                >
                    <div>
                        {entry.name}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {entry.address}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {entry.phoneNumber}
                    </div>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => handleDeleteEntry(entry.id)}
                    >
                        -
                    </button>
                </li>
            );
        })}
    </ul>
) : null}
```

```
const seedEntries = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        userEvent.type(screen.getByTestId("input-name"), "testName" + i);
        userEvent.type(screen.getByTestId("input-address"), "testAddress" + i);
        userEvent.type(screen.getByTestId("input-phone"), "012345678" + i);
        userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /\+/i }));
    }
};
```

Is it possible to have my test run so that each of the deletion buttons are clicked reliably? Currently it appears to be missing every 2nd button (I think due to it being too quick, but I've tried playing around with settimeouts and async awaits to no success) my user-event is on v13.5

Comment: Please provide the code of the component under test.

Comment: @slideshowp2 i have added extra code snippets

Comment: Where does the `entries` come from and what's the `seedEntries` function?

Comment: entries is just an array of objects to be rendered. Its in a useState hook, and I've already been able to successfully test that I can add and delete an entry, and that my DOM updates as expected. 
I'll append my seeding function now, it just fills my entries list with objects, thank you @slideshowp2